# FSL Application initialization failed: couldn't connect to display ":0"

Tags: environment-variables, macos-big-sur

- M1 apple macbookpro
- bigsur 11.0.1

fsl install, then error

```
(base)  -MacBook-Pro  ~ fsl
Application initialization failed: couldn't connect to display ":0"
Error in startup script: couldn't connect to display ":0"
    while executing
"load /usr/local/fsl/extras/lib/libtk8.4.dylib Tk"
    ("package ifneeded" script)
    invoked from within
"package require Tk"
    invoked from within
"if { [  string match -nocase *wish* $MYSHELL ] } {
    package require Tk
#    tk_focusFollowsMouse
#bind Button <Enter> { focus %W ; tk::ButtonEnter ..."
    (file "/usr/local/fsl/tcl/fslstart.tcl" line 18)
    invoked from within
"source [ file dirname [ info script ] ]/fslstart.tcl"
    (file "/usr/local/fsl/tcl/fsl.tcl" line 71)
    invoked from within
"source ${FSLDIR}/tcl/${origname}.tcl"
    (file "/usr/local/fsl/bin/fsl" line 22)
```

then I check my fsl environment,

```
(base) -MacBook-Pro  ~  echo $FSLDIR
/usr/local/fsl
```

```
(base) -MacBook-Pro  ~  flirt -version
FLIRT version 6.0
```

```
(base) -MacBook-Pro  ~  which imcp

/usr/local/fsl/bin/imcp
```

then I check my fsl package, it seems ok, no package missing

```
(base) -MacBook-Pro  ~  cd /usr/local/fsl
(base) -MacBook-Pro  /usr/local/fsl  ls
LICENCE   build     data      extras    lib       src
README    build.log doc       fslpython python    tcl
bin       config    etc       include   refdoc
```

then I check my zsh shell config, it seems right.

```
(base) -MacBook-Pro  /usr/local/fsl  vim ~/.zshrc

# fsl
FSLDIR=/usr/local/fsl
. ${FSLDIR}/etc/fslconf/fsl.sh
PATH=${FSLDIR}/bin:${PATH}
export FSLDIR PATH
(base) -MacBook-Pro  /usr/local/fsl  source ~/.zshrc
```

at last, I restart my MacbookPro, but still fsl failed, error info is the same.

and I also tried `sudo fsl`

```
(base)  ✘ -MacBook-Pro  /usr/local/fsl  sudo fsl
You need to set the FSLDIR environment variable to point to the FSL installation directory before you can run anything.
```

So I think the configuration of fsl environment variables may be wrong, but it seems no problem with the related configuration.

**Why fsl always fails to start?**

**What does the error info mean?**

Much appreciated.

official web:

https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/FslInstallation/MacOsX
https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/FslInstallation/ShellSetup

Answer (score 0):

Well, althouth I failed to run fsl in the terminal, but I found that a new App icon appears on my desk. This FSL icon is the exact entrance to start fsl.

[FSL icon on the desk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxApR.png)

ps: The error info "Application initialization failed: couldn't connect to display “:0” "could be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue on launching fsl using Mac terminal but I can get through with your answer.
Thank you very much.

I right-clicked on the Xquartz icon and choose 'terminal'.
Then I type 'fsl' on Xquartz terminal.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30114842)